# How to read LOBs in OCCI using setDataBuffer()

Tags: c++, oracle, blob, occi

What is the proper way to read LOBs from Oracle when using Application-Managed Data Buffers (setDataBuffer())?

All of the Oracle docs discuss OCCI programming with LOBs using getBlob() and separately about high performance using setDataBuffer(). But the setDataBuffer() docs never discuss LOBS.

We figured something out 15 years ago and use OCI calls to read the blobs following ResultSet::next(). It has worked since Oracle 10 and 12. But that implementation appears broken as we attempt to port to Oracle 19.2.  There have been no code changes in this legacy code...just attempting to build with 19.2.

Answer (score 0):

Please install the demos / examples Into used Client and search for occiclob.cpp in $ORACLE_HOME/rdbms/demo or $ORACLE_HOME/oci/demo
and use readBuffer / writeBuffer
See

https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B10501_01/appdev.920/a96583/cciaadem.htm

```
/**
 * populating the clob;
 */
void populateClob (Clob &clob, int size)
throw (SQLException)
{
Stream *outstream = clob.getStream (1,0);
char *buffer = new char[size];

memset (buffer,'H', size);
outstream->writeBuffer (buffer, size);
char *c = (char *)"";
outstream->writeLastBuffer (c,0);
delete (buffer);
clob.closeStream (outstream);
}

/**
 * printing the clob data as integer stream
 */
void dumpClob (Clob &clob, int size)
throw (SQLException)
{
Stream *instream = clob.getStream (1,0);
char *buffer = new char[size];
memset (buffer, NULL, size);

instream->readBuffer (buffer, size);
cout << "dumping clob: ";
for (int i = 0; i < size; ++i)
  cout << (char) buffer[i];
cout << endl;

delete (buffer);
clob.closeStream (instream);
}
```

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to respond. However the Oracle examples make no mention of ResultSet::setDataBuffer(). I have scoured the C++ Call Interface docs Chapters 12.3 (About Application-Managed Data Buffering) and 12.4 (Using the Array Fetch Using next() Method). All of that is lightning fast...except reading of LOBs is not included. https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/lncpp/optimizing-performance-of-cplusplus-applications.html#GUID-96783A66-4018-4CC4-9D9A-36075BB3FF1A

Comment: writeBuffer() is the equivalent - i worked 17 years for Oracle at 3rd Level Support - Programming languages and Windows Platform. Clob and Blob are replacements/extensions to long raw. All three differ massivly from types like number, date. Varchar etc.

Comment: readBuffer() is a method on Blob. That goes to the heart of my dilemma: How do I get a Blob instance when fetching with ResultSet::next( 100 /*row at a time*/)? Documentation on ResultSet::getCurrentStreamRow() specifically refers to "input Streams". What about output?

Comment: Array processing for multiple rows containing blob, clob, long or long row is not possible as far as I know.